# java.sql.SQLException: No database selected - why?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, odbc, sqlexception

the last days I was trying to learn how to access mySQL databases via Java.
I am able to load the driver and get a connection to the database ( at least I think so, since  I don't get an exception there..)

the code is:

```
    import java.sql.*;
    public class test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
              Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
              System.out.println("driver loaded...");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
              System.out.println("Error in loading the driver..."+e);
              System.exit(0);
            }
            try
            {
                Connection dbConnection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:test","root","password");
                System.out.println("Connection successful...");
                Statement stmt = dbConntection.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate("create table Accounts ( name char(20) )");
             }
             catch(SQLException e)
             {
                  System.out.println("database-ConnectionError: "+e);
                  System.exit(0);
             }   
        }
    }
```

When I execute it, it says:

> driver loaded...
>  Connection successful...
>   database-ConnectionError: java.sql.SQLException: [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.31]No database selected

I really don't know the problem, because I thought the database is selected during the "getConnection" process....
I tried to select a database by adding this line:

```
    stmt.executeUpdate("use test;");
```

after creating the Statement.

unfortunately it didn't work because I got another exception which said I should check on the syntax. I don't understand that either because in my commandline it works just fine...
I don't know if it is possible to use these type of commands via Java so if it isn't, please forgive my mistake.

I hope you can help me and I didn't miss the solution during my own search!

Already Thanks to all who reply and use their time on my problems!

ps. If I forgot to point out some important infos ( I don't think i did) please ask:)

edit: I also tried to create a new database during runtime

```
     stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE test;");
```

this actually works, but the database won't be selected either...

Comment: As an aside: with a JDBC driver, you should not use commands like `use <database>` to switch between databases. Instead you should use `setCatalog` and/or `setSchema` (or specify the database in the connection string). Using `use <database>` may lead to incorrect behavior of the driver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, I am considering my answer to show you another better way for connection with MySQL Database, it's much easier and less nu-expected *Exception(s)*.
You need to do some steps:

1. Download [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and add it to your class path(if you are using an IDE there is add the `.jar` to the library, or there is many tuts on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqhQY7U9Rlc)).
2. Create your database in your MySQL program.
3. See this example below example below I made for you demonstrates how to connect and execute queries on MySQL :

   ```
   import java.sql.*;

   public class MySqlConnection {
     private String MYSQL_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     private String MYSQL_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

     private Connection con;
     private Statement st;
     private ResultSet rs;

     public MySqlConnection() {

       try {
         Class.forName(MYSQL_DRIVER);
         System.out.println("Class Loaded....");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(MYSQL_URL,"","");
         System.out.println("Connected to the database....");
         st = con.createStatement();
         int c =st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Accounts (Name VARCHAR(30))");
         System.out.println("Table have been created.");
         System.out.println(c+" Row(s) have been affected");
         con.close();

       } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException:\n"+ex.toString());
          ex.printStackTrace();

       } catch(SQLException ex) {
           System.out.println("SQLException:\n"+ex.toString());
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
     }

     public static void main(String...args) {
       new MySqlConnection();
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: @sepphuber3: your'r welcome, maybe and maybe ODBC(Not sure) :).

Answer (score 11):

Before you can add a table, you first have to select a database.
you can create a new database with:

```
  CREATE DATABASE database_name
```

you can connect to a specific database with:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename";
String username = "test";
String password = "test";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Comment: I've got the same problem there. Sorry I forgot to say that...
A database is created but still not selected..
how do I do that?

Comment: I connect to my database by appending the url where you connect with the database name if you are running localhost, localhost/databasename

Comment: updated answer with how i connect to my database. This method works fine in my program.

Comment: I believe it should be possible.. But why do you want to use odbc instead of mysql? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated example, which works for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        System.out.println("driver loaded...");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in loading the driver..." + e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try {
        Connection dbConnection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=password");
        System.out.println("Connection successful...");
        Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("create table Accounts ( name char(20) )");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("database-ConnectionError: " + e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Make sure you have added a proper mysql-connector to your build path. I used the: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar`

Comment: thank you! I'll try the connector you used tomorrow! I really hope I can bring make it run^^

Answer (score 1):

```java
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys";
```

Use database name in the URL.
It worked for me